# How to set bootstrap drop down size?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am very new to designing .

My requirement is I want set the col-mg-2 for my select box.

but it's not adujestble Here I attached fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/pno7xojh/2/

If I increse the option length the select box size also increaing. I want to fix it as col-mg-2, if drop down option lenght is much then it i=split two lines.

my code is like

```
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-3">
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="sourceColumn"
         ng-options="column.label for column in operationColumn">
<option value="">Source Columns</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Please Help me?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `select box` one `div` with `col-*-2`

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="joinGeneralInfo">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="sourceTable"
                 ng-options="tabelName.label for tabelName in operationData"
                 ng-change="getOperationColumns(sourceTable)">
        <option value=""> Source Tables</option>
         </select>

      </div>

    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="sourceColumn"
                 ng-options="column in operationColumn">
        <option value="">Source Columns</option>
         </select>
         </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pno7xojh/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

You can adjust the width  CSS

Add and id to your select

```
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="sourceColumn" id="tableID"
     ng-options="column.label for column in operationColumn">
```

Then use CSS to adjust the size:

```
 #tableID
 {
  width:30%;//You can adjust the width to your required size.
  }
```